# django rest framework permission 'isAdminorReadonly'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want only admin to add content to model but that can be read by anyone. Is there any existing permission class that i can use for the same. Or what will be the best approach without object level permissions.Code for the same is

```
class TagList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('title',)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tag.objects.all()
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissionsoranonreadonly)? It will be read only for anonymous users, and admins will be able to edit them as long as you assign the correct permissions.

Answer (score 10):

Let's be specific to your questions.

1. Is there any existing permission class that i can use for the same?

Ans: No. There is no permission provided by drf (till version 3) to provide full access to admin and readonly to anyone (I believe anonymous as well).

2. What will be the best approach without object level permissions?

Ans: I would suggest to have a custom view level permission as follows:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser, SAFE_METHODS

class IsAdminUserOrReadOnly(IsAdminUser):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        is_admin = super(
            IsAdminUserOrReadOnly, 
            self).has_permission(request, view)
        # Python3: is_admin = super().has_permission(request, view)
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS or is_admin
```

Answer (score 9):

**Yes,** there is an existing permission class **[`DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissionsoranonreadonly)** which you can use.

It will grant authorization if the user is authenticated and has the relevant object permissions assigned but will also allow unauthenticated users to have read-only access to the API.

```
class TagList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    # add both permission classes 
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly,)
```

From [DRF documentation:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions)

> [**DjangoModelPermissions**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions)
>   This permission class ties into Django's
>   standard `django.contrib.auth model` permissions. This permission must
>   only be applied to views that has a `.queryset` property set.
>   Authorization will only be granted if the user is `authenticated` and
>   has the relevant model permissions assigned.
>
> `POST` requests require the user to have the `add` permission on the
>   model.
>   `PUT` and `PATCH` requests require the user to have the `change`
>   permission on the model.
>   `DELETE` requests require the user to have the
>   `delete` permission on the model.
>
> [**DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissionsoranonreadonly)
>   **Similar to
>   `DjangoModelPermissions`, but also allows unauthenticated users to have
>   read-only access to the API.**

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser, permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

this will let the admin to `POST`, `DELETE`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `GET`.
and for a authenticated or anonymous user only `GET` is allowed

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom permissions say:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAdminUser, SAFE_METHODS

class ReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS
```

And then call the permission

```
class TagList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    # Supports Boolean operator 'or': |
    permission_classes = [
        IsAdminUser|ReadOnly
     ]
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('title',)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Tag.objects.all()
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried Ansuman's answer, and still wasn't able to use `SAFE_METHODS` without credentials because it inherits `IsAdminUser`.  I inherited the `BasePermission` instead and incorporated the `IsAdminUser` functionality:

```
class IsAdminOrReadOnly(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_staff)
```